# UDP Client Server передача файла

Tags: java, сервер, udp, client

Имеем клиент и сервер, протокол `UDP`. Сервер в состоянии прослушивания, к нему подключается клиент передача данных, это происходит отлично.

Допустим, я передаю файл, с клиента все идет хорошо. Но как мне узнать на сервере, когда ко мне подключается клиент?

Зачем это нужно?

Дабы создать новый файл в системе, принять данные от клиента и записать их в новый файл.

Хочу реализовать также одновременную обработку нескольких клиентов, сделаю поток на каждого. Но опять проблема: Я не могу найти как узнать, когда к UDP серверу подключился клиент.

P.S. Скорее всего это одна-две строчки,но не могу нигде найти нужное.

P.S.S. Использую конечно же DatagramSocket

Comment: Нужен именно протокол UDP

Comment: В UDP нет подключения. к вам просто приходит пакет. И вы решаете что с ним делать, в том числе проверяете от кого он пришел, имея эту информацию и возможно дополнительно некую информацию из самого пакета вы решаете от нового он клиента или от уже существующего и в зависимости от этого добавляете данные к буферу какого нибудь файла, создаете клиента, обрабатываете некую команду, находящуюся в пакете. И кстати по потоку на клиента слишком дорого. обычный асинхронный ввод вывод в одном потоке отлично справится, если нет колоссальных нагрузок

Comment: Тем более что не разобрав пакет вы все равно не узнаете от кого он и следовательно не будете знать какому потоку его отдать. А когда разберете, смысла отдавать другому потоку уже не будет

Comment: В общем всё ясно,спасибо. Но остались пару вопросов,как мне проверить от кого он пришел?я же получаю DatagramPacket и в нем byte[]. Я упускаю какой-то метод?

Comment: а хотя я и сам знаю ответ на этот вопрос, наверно , getAdress, getPort. А клиентов что ли заносить в какой-то ArrayList допустим?

Comment: Не подскажете как будет выглядеть тот момент в коде,когда мне надо будет создать новый файл в системе?(само создание не надо)

Comment: Массив или List или может быть какая нибудь коллекция с хешированием, что бы в ней быстро находить нужный элемент ориентируясь на ip и порт клиента. Т.е. скажем ip и порт собираем в строку `127.0.0.1:6435` и что бы прямо по этой строке достать из коллекции (типы в C# знаю плохо, сами подберите подходящий). И в элементе этой коллекции храните некий тип или структуру описания клиента, в которой будет известно текущее состояние, номер последнего пакета, связь с файлстримом. Думаю лучше именно тип сделать. И не забудьте в протоколе обмена заложить нумерацию пакетов, что бы не перепутать

Comment: Ну и если пакет пришел, а элемента в коллекции еще нет - то это явно новый клиент, убеждаемся что мы готовы разрешить ему писать файл и создаем объект клиента, который если все ok открывает файл

Comment: Большое спасибо,все понятно

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void acceptFile(File file, int port) throws IOException {

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

DatagramPacket pac = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);

DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(port);

FileOutputStream os =new FileOutputStream(file);

try {

s.setSoTimeout(60000);

while (true) {

s.receive(pac);

os.write(data);

 os.flush();
}
} 

catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {

 os.close();

System.out.println("Истекло время ожидания, прием данных закончен");
```

Comment: Принятие самого файла,но как мне узнать когда мне создавать file, который сюда передается

Comment: Могу скинуть целиком код сервера,и клиента

Comment: Интересно, а этот код только на одном компе проверяли или в локалке с одним свитчем ? А то ведь UDP при прохождении через интернет имеют свойство теряться, приходить два раза одно и то же, приходить не в том порядке в каком отправляли. А следовательно надо еще смотреть на порядок пакетов, что не помешало бы отразить в протоколе обмена.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошая идея расширить протокол UDP и добавить туда сессии.

Первый пакет от клиента HELO и (рандомный) идентификатор.

Сервер создает файл отвечает HELO и идентификатором сессии. Сохраняет связь в словарик.

Клиент шлет пакет с заголовком DATA, номер пакета и идентификатор сессии, и сами данные.

Сервер смотрит связь и выстраивает пакеты в правильном порядке и пишет их в файл.
(удп не гарантирует порядок) Сервер запрашивает номера недосталенных пакетов (удп не гарантирует доставку.

Поздравляем - мы изобрели упрощенный RTP протокол.
Посмотрите готовые протоколы на базе UDP и используйте их.